# Amazon MarketplaceWebService (c#) : Missing required MWSAuthToken for Seller

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I'm using MarketplaceWebService API for feeds ( Feeds API Section Client Library - C# - Version 2009-01-01 ) and i have all the requirement access keys but every time i try to call a service i get:

> Caught Exception: **Missing required MWSAuthToken for Seller**.
>   Response Status Code: Unauthorized
>   Error Code: AccessDenied
>   Error Type: Sender
>   Request ID: 5daee826-72a3-4d82-b84f-155936964879
>   XML: Sender`AccessDenied`Missing required MWSAuthToken for Seller.5daee826-72a3-4d82-b84f-155936964879
>   ResponseHeaderMetadata:

Seems this funcionality was added on the version 2014-09-30 ( [Client library updates](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_ES/feeds/Feeds_ClientLibraries.html) )

Where can i download this version? i cant see where is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let the title on [this page](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/feeds/v20090101/cSharp.html) fool you, the download is actually the [c# client 2016-09-21](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/clientlib/feeds/amazon-mws-v20090101-csclient-2016-09-21._CB482805904_.zip) which should include the necessary changes.